# Visual Studio .Net Dependency Management

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit

I have a VS project for an Excel add-in that depends on a C++ COM library I have developed. I would like to be able to build this in x86 and x64 mode from the same solution. However, I have a reference to an x86 build of my C++ lib so when I change the configuration to x64 the compiler does not see the C++ lib (since the reference is to the lib's x86 build).

My question is what is the best / approved way to build different configurations from the same solution without changing references each time.

thanks!

Comment: Is the excel add in c++ as well?

Answer (score 1):

> without changing references each time

There is no "each time" requirement.  Your project's settings are saved *per configuration*.  So you only have to change the linker's "Additional Libraries Directories" setting for your x64 platform target once.  This value automatically becomes active when you build the x64 platform.  And has the original value when you build your Win32 platform.  Make the change both for the Debug and Release configurations.

In fact, you don't have to change any settings at all if the C++ library project is in the same solution.  Starting with VS2012, you can simply use Common Properties + References, Add New Reference button and pick the C++ library from the Projects node.

Comment: But in terms of adding a reference (COM or otherwise) to a .Net project, this seems to be just done once (i.e. Add Reference) and is not on a per-configuration basis as far as i can see in VS2010.

Comment: Surely you noticed "VS2012" in the answer?  I future-proof my answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [TLBimp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  It converts the interface of a com object to a type library that you can use to compile your project.  If you reference the type library, you might be able to build in both configurations.